# how to get the form data value to payload in next 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I am trying to send the form-data then I always get form-data in payload {}, I have logged the state value then got it, but when I set the from-data to submit the form in payload I'm not able to get any value

```
"use client";
import { addCategory } from '@/services/api.method';
import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from 'react';

const AddNew: React.FC = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [image, setImage] = useState<File | null>(null);

    const handleTitleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setTitle(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            setImage(file);
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        formData.append('title', title);
        if (image) {
            formData.append('image', image, image.name);
        }
        try {
            const res = await addCategory(formData);
            console.log('Response from addCategory:', res);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error adding category:', error);
        }
    };
```